# $_nC_r$ probability help

Tags: probability, combinatorics

It's been a while since I've done probability math (a couple years ago in high school).  I play a bit of sheepshead, and we were discussing the odds of one trump being in the blind.  In sheepshead, there are 32 cards; 14 are trump and 18 are fail.  There are two cards in the blind and 3 people playing.  How do you calculate the odds of 0 trump, exactly one trump, at least 1 trump, and 2 trump being in the blind?  I know it has something to do with $_nC_r$, but cannot remember how do it.

Comment: As I've never heard of the game "sheepshead" you'll need to be a bit more clear with what it is you are asking.  If I am understanding you correctly, there are 32 cards, 14 of which are trump, and you are picking two cards from these at random and your question is what the odds are that these two picked cards are trump or not is.  Was there any importance on the number of players?

Comment: @JMoravitz I suppose not, since peeves91's problem did not specify any relation to the players.

Answer (score 0):

Probability in an *equiprobable setting* is simply $Pr(\text{event occurring}) = \frac{\text{\# ways event occurs}}{\text{\# ways regardless}}$

Imagine for a moment that the cards not only are labeled trump or notrump, but also are labeled with numbers.  Considering our sample space as being the ways in which you can select two cards (where order doesn't matter), we notice that each occurrence will be equiprobable so we may use this definition for probability.

The number of ways of selecting two cards for the blind will be $\binom{32}{2}=~_{32}C_2=\frac{32\cdot 31}{2}$

The number of ways of selecting two non-trump for the blind will be $\binom{18}{2}$.  The probability then of having picked both cards to not be trump will be $\frac{\binom{18}{2}}{\binom{32}{2}}=\frac{18\cdot 17}{32\cdot 31}$

Similarly, the number of ways of selecting one non-trump for the blind will be $\binom{18}{1}\cdot\binom{14}{1}=18\cdot 14$, so the probability of this occurring will be $\frac{\binom{18}{1}\cdot\binom{14}{1}}{\binom{32}{2}}=\frac{18\cdot 14\cdot 2}{32\cdot 31}$

Continue similarly for the remaining cases of interest.